# How to handle a two line hover menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, hover

### Context

I am creating a hover menu as such:

|`item 1`|`item 2`|`item 3`|`item 4`|

|`item 5`|`item 6`|`item 7`|`item 8`|

|`..............................`|

|`...DROP DOWN ON ITEM HOVER....`|

|`..............................`|

The drop down is hidden until the user hover over an item. Then the dropdown is shown with the appropriate sub-menu content.

---

### Problem

When I want the sub-menu of `item 1`, I hover over it but then I need to hover over `item 5` to get to the sub-menu, so it changes to the one for `item 5` instead of `item 1`.

Her's a fiddle to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/r8dg9pft/

How can I handle this problem properly ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `this` is `window` inside of `setTimeout` . Can include `html` at Question ? Can describe _"it messes up the whole hovering process"_ ?

Comment: what is setTimeout should do? ..

Answer (score 0):

You're issue is that you have a hover event only on the menu items, therefore as soon as you hover out, the sub menu disappears. So you would need to create another hover on a global div to make it work :

```
$(function () {
    $('#main').hover(function () {
        $(this).find("span").hover(function()
        {
        if ($(this).hasClass('item')) {
            $('#sub-menu').text($(this).text());
        }
        $('#sub-menu').show();
        });
    }, function () {
        $('#sub-menu').hide();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r8dg9pft/1/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the code in my question wasn't updated with the one of the fiddle. Please refer to the fiddle to see exactly what i'm trying to achieve

Comment: I still see the old code for which i provided the solution. Do you have the link to the updated fiddle ?